# Can't access websites that I am authenticated on (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: networking, ubuntu, google-chrome, firefox, git

This is my first question so apologies if it doesn't follow any good practices.

Basically, I can't seem to access any websites that I was previously authenticated on. E.g. Github, Jira, but not YouTube for some reason. Of course, everything works fine in incognito mode. Git does not seem to work as well with it returning `fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly.`

I've tested on Firefox and Chrome

My system is running **Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS on an ethernet of MTU 1500**. Strangely, if I connect my PC to my mobile hotspot, everything works.

What I've tried:

- Changing DNS to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4.
- Resetting my router to factory settings
- Disabling IPV6 on firefox

What I expect:

- Access websites that I am authenticated on
- Be able to make commits with `git`
- To fix this headache of a problem

**EDIT (7-7-21):**

More information about visiting some of the websites using **incognito on chrome**.

On logging in, the page gets stuck on loading. Nothing else gets requested and it just stays like that with no other errors. See the following screenshots using dev tools on Github and ICloud:

[Network panel on Github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwfrS.png)

[Console panel on Github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcB2z.png)

[Console panel on ICloud](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWz5z.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide more information when you visit one of those websites.  Please do not reply to this comment. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240815/git-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly) seems to suggest that the problem is a network adapter problem.

Answer (score 0):

After digging around the internet I've come across this: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2291570

In short, **I've changed my MTU from 1500 to 1200** and now everything is working!

[Screenshot of MTU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOQDq.png)

However, I'm not familiar with what MTU does. Please let me know if this bad practice or should be temporary. Else, I'll close this issue, or if you're a mod - feel free to close it.